# Button doesn't stay inside form "card"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to improve my Bootsrap skills but need help for an issue about card and forms.

Trying to fit form in card but couldn't make it. Has anyone an idea about this issue?

```
<div class="row row-content col-sm-8">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-header card-warning" style="width: 100%">Featured</h3>
            <form class="form-group col-sm-12 row">
                <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <label><strong>Number of Guests</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-9 col-sm-9 align-items-center">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                                            </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 align-items-center">
                    <p style="padding: 10px"></p>
                    <p><strong>Date and Time</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 form-inline">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Date">

                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Time</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Time">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col col-offset">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Reserve</a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Reserve button stays outside of card, why form doesn't fit to card here?
[image]

Button should be in card also..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as changing code like this.

```
<div class="row-content col-sm-8">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-header card-warning" style="width: 100%">Featured</h3>
            <form class="col-sm-12 row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 align-items-center">
                    <label><strong>Number of Guests</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 input-group">
                    <label class="radio-inline" style="padding-left:">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 1
                                            </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 2
                                            </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 3
                                            </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1"> 4
                                            </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2"> 5
                                            </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3"> 6
                                            </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 align-items-center">
                    <p style="padding: 10px"></p>
                    <p><strong>Date and Time</strong></p>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 input-group align-items-center row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o fa-fw"></i></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Date" placeholder="Date">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i></span></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button" placeholder="Time">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col col-offset">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Reserve</a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```